# Cable for 4Gb Fibre Channel

Tags: fiber, layer1, cable

I have two servers with 4Gb Fibre Channel HBA adapters.

Looking for cable for them, I found reasonably priced cables that say they're 10Gb.
I know that if this was copper, it would be overkill, but I could use CAT7 cable for 100Mb Ethernet.
Is fiber compatible in the same way?  Like a rating.
Or is the fiber tuned to specific wavelengths making a 10Gb cable incompatible with 4Gb ports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every piece of (optical) FC gear I've ever seen is multimode, 850nm. So just about any MM cable will work -- assuming you aren't stringing the stuff half a kilometer. Most "10Gb" fiber cables are 50 micron MM, so they should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

you should use LC-LC connector multimode fiber. 
but you should consider the distance between two server. 
for under 10 meter you can use all kind of multimode fiber. om1, om2, om3, om4 
om1 and om2 have core width 63 micron and om3 and om4 have 50 micron and more expensive

Comment: Thanks, I got this working 6 months ago, but this info could be useful to anybody else searching for the same question. In this case, the two servers are next to each other in the same rack, so cable length wasn't an issue.